# How to analyze High Ping spikes (Mac)

Tags: macos, wifi, ping

I have one Mac which experiences WiFi spikes in all networks it connects to. Here is my Ping over 10s; there is a spike to about 230ms about every second, how can I fix this???

[image]

I already tried to disable location services -> no change

The Command: `tail -f /var/log/wifi.log` brings out this:
[image]

Comment: Do you see this spikes only from one specific Mac, or from all devices within the same network? Does the Mac show the spikes only in this network, or in all it connects to?

Comment: @nohillside The Mac shows these symptoms on all Wifi Networks it connects to. Other devices in the same network don't have any problems -> it's a problem of the Mac itself.

Comment: Which tool provides you this graphic?

Comment: I'm also wondering what tool was used for this?